# Need to spawn a sourced shell script using expect

Tags: bash, environment-variables, expect, interaction

i'm using expect to automate some bash scripts. All goes right until i need to execute a sourced script; then i get this error:

```
couldn't execute "source setNAME.sh": no such file or directory
while executing
"spawn "source setNAME.sh""
(file "./setNAME.exp" line 2)
```

I use expect in a basic way (spawn/expect/send/interact); the problem is with spawn. Let me show a very easy example:

Script to read a name, echo the value and export to the environment as 'NAME':

```
/home/edu/scripts [] cat setNAME.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Your name?"
read name
export NAME=$name
echo "Provided NAME is $name"
```

If you execute with 'source' then the input value will be exported as environment variable. Just what i need:

```
/home/edu/scripts [] source setNAME.sh
Your name?
Dennis
Provided NAME is Dennis

/home/edu/scripts [] echo $NAME
Dennis
```

Let's to use expect to avoid interaction, setting 'edu' as the name:

```
/home/edu/scripts [] cat setNAME.exp
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn setNAME.sh
expect "Your name?"
send edu\r
interact

/home/edu/scripts [] setNAME.exp
spawn setNAME.sh
Your name?
edu
Provided NAME is edu

/home/edu/scripts [] echo $NAME
Dennis
```

But the name, obviously, is still Dennis: 'edu' is shown at sh script output but not exported as NAME because expect script spawns the setNAME.sh script WITHOUT source (or dot before script).

The problem is that I CAN'T DO THIS because i get the error commented at the beginning.

Any ideas to solve/afford this need ?

In my case the script is much more complex and other solutions are also invalid, for example things like this:

```
source script.sh << EOF
<option1>
<option2>
...
EOF
```

That's the reason i'm trying to use expect...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: excellent first question, Sorry, not an expect expert, but did you try `spawn source setname.csh`? Good luck.

Comment: Yes of course that the first thing i did (sorry I didn't explain well). I don't understand the reason but surely there is one. I tried with quotes too: spawn "source <script>", but same results...

Comment: try turning on all shell debugging levels, in csh it is `set -vx` (and probably similar in expect). Then you can see each line as it is executed both before and after variable values are assigned. That may give you a clue. As this is a simple script, you also might try implementing just this much in `bash`, edit your question with those results and tag with `bash`. You'll get a lot more help then. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, i modified the original question using bash instead of csh. I tried sh/ksh/bash with the same result. Hope the new tag helps to found a solution. I debug (set -x in ksh/bash and -xv in csh) but no idea of what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source` is a shell builtin, not a system command, so you first need to spawn a shell then send the source command to it. That shell will then have the value in the NAME variable

Comment: ok, it works, thank u very much. Summing up: the hint is to spawn /bin/sh, and then send "source <script>\r".

Comment: @eramos Can you please help me how can I source if I execute script from spawn itself ?  Instead of send "source script". ?                                                                       "I tried spawn /bin/sh ssh -t  $user@$ip sudo bash script {*}$argv"  but im getting following error "/usr/bin/ssh: /usr/bin/ssh: cannot execute binary file
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"

Comment: Why do you spawn /bin/sh instead of ssh directly?

Comment: @glennjackman Im trying to Source a shell script from expect script in Spawn itself.. Is it possible?

Comment: Please ask a separate question